# x-loader ECC error

Tags: android, embedded

It seems that I have incorrectly updated an x-loader using Nand Flashing procedure. Now I have to flash module, but it gives me error, I am using OM3730 EVM and A8 module.

Error:

[image]

How might I resolve this unfortunate situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebuild x-loader with right ECC settings and then reflash it using USB or serial cable.

Just set SYSBOOT pins to boot from USB or serial and use appropriate flashing tool.

There is article for BeagleBoard - http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard#Serial_and_USB_boot.
But it will work for your board too.